# Get elevation from GeoTIFF using node-gdal lib?

Tags: gdal, node-js

I developed [an open and free Geo API for Portugal](https://github.com/jfoclpf/geoapi.pt) and now I'd like to provide altitude without the need of external APIs, that is, using the GeoTIFF file provided by the government agency. I developed this API solely in Node.JS

Anyone with experience with [GDAL lib for node](https://github.com/naturalatlas/node-gdal) can tell me how to get elevation from a GeoTIFF file? I have been checking other answers here with Python or Java but the methods/function names seem quite different.